# Windows Grep \K lookbehind not working

Tags: windows, command-line, grep

I have an html file that contains:

```
<h2><a href="http://example.com" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to example.com">Example.com Portal</a></h2>
```

I am trying to extract "Example.com Portal" using the following code with GNU Grep 2.5.4 for Windows.

```
grep.exe -o -P -i "<h2><a\shref=.*>\K.*(?=</a></h2>)" "index.html"
```

I used `\K` since `(?<=pattern)` lookbehind does not allow indefinite length wildcards like `*` in the pattern. The code above does not work and I am not sure if there's something wrong with it or if my grep version does not support the `\K` lookbehind.

Comment: The regex is fine. Windows quoting magic, maybe?

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless problem description. What actually happens, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: "doesn't work" means nothing is printed

Comment: I have `grep (GNU grep) 2.24` from latest GitBash (Git 2.7.4) and your grep command works just fine. May be try with another version.

Comment: And there are usually native tools to do the same thing. For example you can use the following PowerShell command: `(Select-String C:\temp\index.html -Pattern '.*<a.*>(.*)</a>.*').Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Seems like the grep version that I have is the problem. I tried with pcregrep and the command works.